# On notice period without any offer

Tags: job-change, india, notice-period

I am on notice period and 30 September, 2019 will be my last day. Currently I am in the process of recruitment with another company and have completed one round of interviews. What should I tell HR if the recruitment process extends past the end of my notice period?

And also what should I tell to other company HR after the 30th? Is it going to affect the CTC (cost to company/salary)?

Comment: I would not mention about your confirmed resignation to new employer at all. It simply offer them more leverage to low-ball you on contract negotiation. Simply negotiate terms in contract as if you did not resign, and setup the starting date as you please.

Comment: I can't understand this question. I had to read "30 sep,19" three times to understand it. I don't know what "What should i tell to hr if it happened after 30 sep" means. I don't know what "what should i tell to other company hr after 30 sep" means and I don't know what "ctc".

Comment: Hi @KeithLoughnane - 30 sep, 19 is a date (the 30th of September, 2019). CTC is "cost to company" - an acronym used in India for salary. The other sentence you quoted seems to mean "if I am past my last date and still in the recruiting process, should I tell potential employers that I have already finished my notice period?" The OP is concerned that finishing their notice period and becoming unemployed before finding a new job will affect their salary negotiations with the new employer.

Comment: Why did you resign before you had a job offer?

Answer (score 7):

On September 30th you will be unemployed. If you don’t start somewhere else, you will not get paid a salary. There will be no extra cost for the other company, you being without income is not their problem.

Telling them that you will be unemployed may weaken your negotiation position, so I wouldn’t volunteer that information.

I would strongly recommend that you apply at other companies as well or you might get into financial trouble if the offer from the new company doesn’t materialise.